# How to open a url in a new window using SSRS 2008 reportviewer control

Tags: javascript, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I need to open a web page in a new window as a link from a cell in an SSRS 2008 report. I found a reference on the web to say the best way to do this is to put in something like:

="javascript:void(window.open('"+ Fields!ReferURL.Value + "','_blank'))"

where the Fields!ReferURL.value is the page you want to navigate to in another window.

This works perfectly in report manager once the report has been deployed.

However, when we run the report from within a web page using the reportviewer control, the link does nothing at all.

Does anyone know how to get round this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a page viewer control and appending &rc:LinkTarget=_blank to the end of the report url. Then remove the javascript from the cell's jump to URL action, replace it with the just the URL you want to jump to. The &rc:LinkTarget=_blank forces all links on the report to open in a new window.

Ex.
http://yourserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?path_to_your_report&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=_blank

I don't think this applies to viewing the report in a report viewer. I don't believe you can specify URL parameters with the report viewer. However I haven't found any features the report viewer offers over the page viewer (for standard mode reports).